# C++ runtime datatype identification & avoiding switch-case

Tags: c++

I have the following code that I hope to simplify and minimize duplication.

```
// Gather.cpp
void GetParam()
{
    ProParameter * param; // 3rd party struct
    ProParamvalue proValue; // 3rd party struct
    ProParameterValueGet( param, & proValue ); // this is a call to a 3rd Party API
    shared_ptr< CPartParam > pParam; // CPartParam is my class

    /* The .type in switch() statement is an enum with following definition:
    typedef enum  param_value_types  {
       PRO_PARAM_DOUBLE  = 50, /* use d_val from ProParamvalueValue to set value *
       PRO_PARAM_STRING  = 51, /* use s_val from ProParamvalueValue to set value *
    }  ProParamvalueType;
    */
    // WUD LOVE TO ELIMINATE THE SWITCH-CASE
    switch( proValue.type ) // .type is enum as above
    {
        case PRO_PARAM_DOUBLE: // 3rd party enum value
            pParam->SetValue( proValue.value.d_val );
            break;
        case PRO_PARAM_STRING: // 3rd party enum value
            pParam->SetValue( proValue.value.s_val );
            break;
        default:
            break;
     }
}

// PartData.h
class CPartParam
{
public:
    enum ValueType
    {
    DOUBLE,
    STRING
    };

    ValueType m_eValueType;
    double m_dVal;
    wstring m_sVal;
    bool SetValue( const double & dVal );
    bool SetValue( const wstring & sVal );
};

// PartData.cpp
// There is one overload for each data-type. WUD LOVE TO CONDENSE TO A SINGLE METHOD/TEMPLATE FUNCTION THAT CAN SET THE VALUE IRRESPECTIVE OF THE DATA-TYPE.
void CPartParam::SetValue( const double & dVal )
{
    m_eValueType = DOUBLE;
    m_dVal = dVal;
}

bool CPartParam::SetValue( const wstring & sVal )
{
    m_eValueType = STRING;
    m_sVal = sVal;
}
```

As can be seen the datatype of the "proValue.type" is determined at runtime, which forces me to write repetitive code: CPartParam::SetValue() overloads (one for each data-type). I would LOVE it if I can avoid the switch-case loop in GetParam(), if at all possible.

There is more repetitive code with a 2nd switch-case when the data stored in CPartParam shared_ptr has to retrieved (i.e. CPartParam::GetValue).

I have shown sample code (may not necessarily compile), but will fix if anyone wants to compile.

I have shown only two data-types (PRO_PARAM_DOUBLE, PRO_PARAM_STRING) but there are a handful more.

The only restrictions I have are that our dev team still uses Boost 1.36.0, Visual Studio 2005 (primary reason is due to the 3rd party library). We need to use boost::serialization, so recommendations to use any new data-types has the restriction that that new data-type must be serializable using boost::serialization in boost version 1.36.0.

Comment: What duplicate code are you trying to eliminate?

Comment: @john-dibling Whups. I guess I should have been more specific. Editing code to show duplication. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Boost.Variant (which is available in Boost 1.36.0). This provides a `variant` type that encapsulates the discriminated union (taking the place of your `CPartParam` type), and a `static_visitor` idiom that takes the place of the switch.

Comment: @mike-seymour Thanks for your answer. Would the following be the example I would follow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237775/how-to-return-different-classes-from-one-function/2237837#2237837 ?

Comment: @ossandcad: yes, that looks like a good example. Also see the documentation at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/variant.html, which also has a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for run-time inheritance. The best solution really is a `boost::variant`, which is nicely optimized and such.