# What are the SQL data types to use in a C++ program?

Tags: c++, sql-server

I am writing an C++ application using OLE DB interfaces to read tables in SQL Server 2008. The columns in my table are of type VARCHAR. In my program, I have to check the data type of the column and do some stuff, but don't know how to check SQL datatypes in C++ program.

What the macros for types and which header has them?

Thanks,
Sanish.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eshhha8h.aspx

Comment: I have read the column datatype from SYS.COLUMNS view using OLE DB APIs and have 167 (for VARCHAR) stored in an interger variable in my C++ program. Now I have a switch case where I check for different data types. I need to know the macro to check against in the switch case.

Comment: is that what do you need: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722536/c-runtime-datatype-identification-avoiding-switch-case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722536/c-runtime-datatype-identification-avoiding-switch-case) ?

Comment: Something similar to this - the meta-data of the table is as follows:
name system_type_id max_length
C2 167 4000
C3 56 4
C4 62 8
C2 is VARCHAR(167), C2 is INTEGER(56) and C3 is FLOAT(62), now I have to check these types in a C++ program in a switch case. (I think I should have given this information initially itself to make my question clear)